# How to get child process from parent process

Tags: linux, shell, process, child-process

Is it possible to get the child process id from parent process id in shell script?

I have a file to execute using shell script, which leads to a new process **process1** (parent process). This **process1** has forked another process **process2**(child process). Using script, I'm able to get the pid of **process1** using the command:

```
cat /path/of/file/to/be/executed
```

but i'm unable to fetch the pid of the child process.

Comment: Which child and which parent process are you talking about? By definition, a shell script is executed by a shell process! And why do you ask? Show your script please!

Comment: I'll rephrase my question

Comment: Wait... how does that `cat` command give you a PID ?

Comment: It really seems that you are very confused!

Comment: I second @BasileStarynkevitch : please show us your script, or at least the relevant part.

Comment: And explain what exactly are *process1* and *process2* ... (what program are they each running). If you are coding these programs, add into them the functionality to write their pid in some file (like `/var/run/your-program.pid`...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch how to do this in c? how to get the process tree of a given pid in c language?

Comment: @y_159: **The C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) don't even mention processes**. On Linux, use programmatically [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to get information about processes

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch so the only way to do this is to scan the whole proc filesystem and get the ppid of a process and then one can build  a process tree?

Comment: @y_159. Use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on programs similar to yours (e.g. on `ps` or `top`) to find out what [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) are involved, or take inspiration from existing projects -similar to yours- on [github](https://github.com/) or [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Just use :

```
pgrep -P $your_process1_pid
```

Comment: The current process being the shell process!

Comment: pgrep -P \`pidofproc /path/to/your/process1\`

Comment: pgrep -P 'ppid' is listing the dead process too. How to list only active process?

Answer (score 71):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, does this help?

```
ps --ppid <pid of the parent>
```

Comment: the question tagged with "linux"

Answer (score 28):

I've written a script to get all child process pids of a parent process.
Here is the code. Hope it will help.

```
function getcpid() {
    cpids=`pgrep -P $1|xargs`
#    echo "cpids=$cpids"
    for cpid in $cpids;
    do
        echo "$cpid"
        getcpid $cpid
    done
}

getcpid $1
```

Answer (score 18):

To get the child process and thread,
`pstree -p PID`.
It also show the hierarchical tree

Answer (score 16):

You can get the `pids` of all child processes of a given parent process `<pid>` by reading the `/proc/<pid>/task/<tid>/children` entry.

This file contain the pids of first level child processes.
Recursively do this for all children pids.

For more information head over to https://lwn.net/Articles/475688/

Answer (score 15):

The shell process is `$$` since it is a [special parameter](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html)

On Linux, the  [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) filesystem gives a lot of information about processes. Perhaps
[pgrep(1)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_pgrep.htm) (which accesses `/proc`) might help too.

So try `cat /proc/$$/status` to get the status of the shell process.

Hence, its parent process id could be retrieved with e.g.

```
  parpid=$(awk '/PPid:/{print $2}' /proc/$$/status)
```

Then use `$parpid` in your script to refer to the parent process pid (the parent of the shell).

But I don't think you need it!

Read some [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) (or with caution [advanced bash scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/), which has mistakes) and [advanced linux programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Notice that some server daemon processes (wich usually need to be unique) are explicitly writing their pid into `/var/run`, e.g. the  `sshd` server daemon is writing its pid into the textual file `/var/run/sshd.pid`). You may want to add such a feature into your own server-like programs (coded in C, C++, Ocaml, Go, Rust or some other *compiled* language).

Comment: From #bash on chat.freenode.net's greybot:
The infamous "Advanced" Bash Scripting Guide should be avoided unless you know how to filter out the junk. It will teach you to write bugs, not scripts. In that light, the BashGuide was written: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide;
Just thought I'd mention it!

Answer (score 9):

```
ps -axf | grep parent_pid
```

Above command prints respective processes generated from `parent_pid`, hope it helps.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
root@root:~/chk_prgrm/lp#

 parent...18685

 child... 18686


root@root:~/chk_prgrm/lp# ps axf | grep frk

 18685 pts/45   R      0:11  |       \_ ./frk

 18686 pts/45   R      0:11  |       |   \_ ./frk

 18688 pts/45   S+     0:00  |       \_ grep frk
```

Answer (score 4):

You can print the PID of all child processes invoked by a parent process:

`pstree -p <PARENT_PID> | grep -oP '\(\K[^\)]+'`

This prints a list of pids for the main process and its children recursively

Comment: This is hacky, but it works, thanks.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know `\K` exists. I would have used `grep -oP '(?<=\()[^\)]+'`. More info about `\K`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33573989/318765

Answer (score 2):

I used the following to gather the parent process and child processes of a specific process PID:

`ps -p $PID --ppid $PID --forest | tail -n +2 | awk '{print$1}'`

Note, this will not work to find child processes of child processes.

Answer (score 0):

For the case when the process tree of interest has more than 2 levels (e.g. Chromium spawns 4-level deep process tree), `pgrep` isn't of much use. As others have mentioned above, *procfs* files contain all the information about processes and one just needs to read them. I built a CLI tool called [Procpath](https://pypi.org/project/Procpath/) which does exactly this. It reads all `/proc/N/stat` files, represents the contents as a JSON tree and expose it to JSONPath queries.

To get all descendant process' comma-separated PIDs of a non-root process (for the root it's `..stat.pid`) it's:

```
$ procpath query -d, "..children[?(@.stat.pid == 24243)]..pid"
24243,24259,24284,24289,24260,24262,24333,24337,24439,24570,24592,24606,...
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    // Create a child process     
    int pid = fork();

    if (pid > 0)
    {

            int j=getpid();

            printf("in parent process %d\n",j);
    }
    // Note that pid is 0 in child process
    // and negative if fork() fails
    else if (pid == 0)
    {





            int i=getppid();
            printf("Before sleep %d\n",i);

            sleep(5);
            int k=getppid();

            printf("in child process %d\n",k);
    }

    return 0;
```

}

Comment: this code helps you from init() takes a orphan process as  its child