# How to get all descendent child process id of pid in c in linux

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, pid

If I `fork` and the child process then `exec` and  creates more child processes (which themselves can create more processes) , how do I get a list of `pid`s of all the descendent process from the first process?

Is there a better way then looping though `/proc/` and checking the `PPid` (the parent of process's id) of each of process?

Comment: the answer from that question using pgrep -P  only gives the child process pids of a pid,  NOT all processes that the children of that child might have created which themselves may have created more processes.

Comment: Sure, but at that point you just apply recursion.

Comment: Fair enough I recuse using pgrep -P

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Not sure about it being a duplicate, as the question you refer to is specific to shell scripting, which has different solutions than this question, which is C-related, and may have, for example(?), a kernel call as a solution?

Comment: C does not provide a standard way to achieve this through system calls.

Comment: I've answered this question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743879/how-to-get-child-process-from-parent-process/63425440#63425440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating through /proc is the "standard" way to do this. That's how `ps` and friends (`pstree`, etc.) are implemented.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for commands to see the process tree, check below commands.

```
ps -ejH
ps axjf
pstree $PID
```

Check the man pages of `ps` and `pstree` commands.