# How to child process can print its root parents ID

Tags: c, linux

If in a simple C program I am writing 4 calls to the `fork()` API and when I execute this program then the total processes created will be 16 on Linux.

1. Using getpid() can get the process id of that current process.
2. Using getppid() can get the parent process id of the calling process.

> Question: How can the last child know the process id of the first process
>   (the ancestor's parent id) from which I call the `fork()` API four times?

NOTE: **The assumption is that all processes are running; nobody died.**

Comment: Can you please post the code? It is not clear to me what do you mean with "writing 4 times fork() ... total processes created will be 16".

Comment: int main{ fork();fork();fork();fork();return 0;} in this condition how can we write a program to find that process id.

Comment: I think this is the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533979/how-to-get-all-descendent-child-process-id-of-pid-in-c-in-linux

Comment: @VinodPatidar, please post the actual code as an exit to the question with an additional code segment.   Also, that series of calls to `fork()` is a very bad idea as it does not properly handle failures, etc

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
first = getpid()
```

before all the forks, and use that variable in the children.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use process tree command called `ps l` (for ppid seperate table is there.)

2) Using `getppid()` you can check recursively and reach to main process.  Here you need some smart logic for this.