# How do I find the current process running on a particular PBS job

Tags: linux, pbs, qsub, torque

I am trying to write a script to provide diagnostics on processes. I have submitted a script to a job scheduling server using qsub. I can easily find the node that the job gets sent to. But I would like to be able to find what process is currently being run.
ie. I have a list of different commands in the submitted script, how can I find the current one that is running, and the arguments passed to it?

example of commands in script

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "display('here'),quit"
python runsomethings.py
```

I would like to see whether the nodes is currently executing the first or second line.

Answer (score 2):

When you submit a job, `pbs_server` pass your task to `pbs_mom`. `pbs_mom` process/daemon actually executes your script on the execution node. It

> ["**creates a new session as identical user**."](https://www.ceng.metu.edu.tr/_media/hpc/documents/introduction-to-hpc-concepts-3-pbs-internals.pdf?rev=)

This means ***invoking a shell***. You specialize the shell at the top of the script marking your choice with shebang: `#!/bin/bash`).

It's clear, that ***`pbs_mom` stores process (shell) `PID`*** somewhere to kill the job and to monitor if the job (shell process) have finished.

---

***UPD. based on @Dmitri Chubarov comment***: `pbs_mom` stores subshell `PID` internally in memory after calling `fork()`, and in the `.TK` file which is under `torque` installation directory: `/var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs` on my system.

Dumping file internals in decimal mode (`<job_number>`, `<queue_name>` should be your own values):

`$ hexdump -d /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/<job_number>.<queue_name>.TK`

have disclosed, that in my torque implementation it is stored in position
`00000890 + offset 4*2 = 00000898` (it is hex value of first byte of `PID` in `.TK` file) and has a length of `2` bytes.
For example, for shell `PID=27110` I have:

```
0000890   00001   00000   00001   00000   27110   00000   00000   00000
```

***Let's recover `PID` from `.TK` file***:

```
$ hexdump -s 2200 -n 2 -d /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/jobs/<job_number>.<queue_name>.TK | tr -s ' ' | cut -s -d' ' -f 2
27110
```

This way you've found subshell PID.

Now, monitor process list on the execution node and find name of child processes (getcpid function is a slighlty modified version of that [posted earlier on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22526892)):

```
function getcpid() {
    cpids=`pgrep -P $1|xargs`
    for cpid in $cpids;
    do
        ps -p "$cpid" -o comm=
        getcpid $cpid
    done
}
```

At last,

```
getcpid <your_PID>
```

gives you the child processes' names (note, there will be some garbage lines, like task numbers). **This way you will finally know, what command is currently running on the execution node.**

---

Of course, for each task monitored, you should obtain the `PID` and process name on the execution node after doing

`ssh <your node>`

You can automatically retrieve node name(s) in `<node/proc+node/proc+...>` format (process it further to obtain bare node names):

```
qstat -n <job number> | awk '{print $NF}' | grep <pattern_for_your_node_names>
```

***Note:***
The `PID` method is reliable and, as I believe, optimal.
Search by name is worse, it provides you unambiguous result only if your invoke different commands in your scripts, and no user executes the same software on the node.

```
ssh <your node>
ps aux | grep matlab
```

*You will know if `matlab` runs.*

Comment: The shell invoked by `pbs_mom` is a child process of `pbs_mom`. `pbs_mom` just calls `fork()` that returns the PID of the shell into the parent process. To survive `pbs_mom` restart, Torque also stores job data that includes the PID in a binary form in a per-job file located in `mom_priv` directory. The `*.TK` file contains a PID that can be used to kill the job.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and elegant way to do it is to print to a log file

`

```
ARGS=" $A $B $test "
echo "running MATLAB now with args: $ARGS" >> $LOGFILE
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "display('here'),quit"

PYARGS="$X $Y"
echo "running Python now with args: $ARGS" >> $LOGFILE
python runsomethings.py
```

`

And monitor the output of $LOGFILE using `tail -f $LOGFILE`