# Traversing the process hierarchy of a process in C

Tags: c, linux

I am currently working on a program that tracks the memory usage of the hierarchy of a certain process in linux. While it is possibe to find the parent ID quite easily, it is difficult to find the childs of that particular process. Is there any way I can find all the childs of a process and their childs and so on without resorting to shell scripts?

Comment: I know  no *C* way to do it. You will have to process the output of the `ps` command, or browse the `/proc` folder to get a list of all active processes with their id and parent id and rebuild the tree from there. And beware of race conditions like process starting or ending during that operation...

Comment: I've answered this question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743879/how-to-get-child-process-from-parent-process/63425440#63425440

Answer (score 1):

The process hierarchy is the other way around - children track their parent.
You'd have to go through the whole of `/proc` to check the parent of each process. This is what all these tools implement:

- [How can I recursively get all child process for a given pid?](https://superuser.com/q/363169/113004)
- [How to get child process from parent process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17743879/476716)

Alternatively, if you can monitor the process from its start, e.g. like `strace` does, then you could track all the `fork`/`clone` system calls and record the returned child pid.